# Difference between recursive task and recursive action in ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

We can submit two types of tasks to `forkJoinPool`. one is `RecursiveAction` and other is `RecursiveTask`.

What is the difference between both of them?

Comment: `RecursiveTask` returns a value, `RecursiveAction` doesn't. It's like `Task` vs `Runnable`.

Comment: Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the first lines of their respective Javadocs:

> - [[`RecursiveTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html) is] A recursive result-bearing ForkJoinTask.
> - [[`RecursiveAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) is] A recursive resultless ForkJoinTask.

Although technically, `RecursiveAction` *does* return a value, it's just always `null`, because it's a `ForkJoinTask<Void>`, and that's the only possible value of `Void`.

Answer (score 2):

They are alike except `RecursiveTask` returns a result while `RecursiveAction` has no return value.